# Using a Micro SD Module in ESP32: file.available() returning false

Tags: file, esp32

I'm trying to get the first file in an SD Card, read it's content, delete the file and return the content.
I think firstFile.available() is returning False. Using the SD.h lib. Thank you for reading

```
String getFirstFile() {
  File root = SD.open("/");
  File firstFile;
  char firstFileName[9];
  while (File file = root.openNextFile()) { 
    char fileName[9];
    strcpy(fileName, file.name()); // changed to strcpy and file.name()
    if (!firstFile.available()) {
      firstFile = file;
      strncpy(firstFileName, fileName, 9);
      firstFileName[8] = '\0';
      Serial.println(firstFileName);
    } else if (strcmp(fileName, firstFileName) < 0) { // added else if clause
      firstFile = file; // updated firstFile;
      strncpy(firstFileName, fileName, 9); // updated firstFileName
      firstFileName[8] = '\0';
    }
    file.close();
  }
  root.close();
  String str = "";
  if (firstFile.available()) {
    char fullPath[10]; // added a new variable for the full path
    strcpy(fullPath, "/"); // copied the "/" character to the full path
    strcat(fullPath, firstFileName); // concatenated the file name to the full path
    firstFile = SD.open(fullPath); // changed to open the file by the full path
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    int len;
    while ((len = firstFile.read((uint8_t*)buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) { // added cast to uint8_t*
      buffer[len] = '\0';
      str = String(buffer); // changed to String constructor
    }
    firstFile.close();

    SD.remove(firstFileName);
  }
  return str;
}
```

I've been trying to get this function to work. It used to work on Arduino with the SDFat.h lib, but it is not working for me in ESP32.
It is getting the file names in each iteration of the loop, however, because !firstFile.available() is true, is always replacing it, also, it is not entering the second if to load the string and delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

In the first while loop, the variable `firstFile` is set to the `file` object, but it does not create a copy of it:

```
firstFile = file;
```

Therefore, when the method `firstFile.close()` is called, the attribute `firstFile.available()` becomes False.

I attempted to copy the file object, but it failed. So I made the following modifications:

```
String getFirstFile() {
  // Open the root directory
  File root = SD.open("/");
  File firstFile;
  File file;
  String firstFileName;

  while (file = root.openNextFile()) { 
    String fileName = file.name();
    // Skip the system folder
    if (fileName == SYSTEM_FOLDER) {
      file.close();
      continue;
    }
    // Find the first file name in alphabetical order
    if (firstFileName == "") {
      firstFileName = fileName;
      Serial.println(firstFileName);
    } else if (fileName.compareTo(firstFileName) < 0) {
      firstFileName = fileName;
      Serial.println(firstFileName);
    }
    file.close();
  }
  // Close the root directory
  root.close();

  // Reserve some memory for the string variable
  String str;
  str.reserve(256);

  // Check if there is a valid first file name
  if (firstFileName != "") {
    Serial.print("Found: ");
    Serial.println(firstFileName);    // Build the full path of the first file and open it
    String fullPath = "/";
    fullPath.concat(firstFileName);
    firstFile = SD.open(fullPath);
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    int len;
    // Read and append the file content to the string variable
    while ((len = firstFile.read((uint8_t*)buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
      buffer[len] = '\0';
      str += buffer;
    }
    // Close and remove the first file
    firstFile.close();
    SD.remove(fullPath.c_str());
  }
  return str;
}
```